# How to escape slashes for mysql insert?

Tags: php, mysql

This is answered everywhere and I simply can't see what's wrong with my code:

```
print 'https://www.facebook.com/someURL'.'<br />';
print addslashes('https://www.facebook.com/someURL').'<br />';
print mysql_real_escape_string('https://www.facebook.com/someURL').'<br />';
```

Output is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/someURL
https://www.facebook.com/someURL
https://www.facebook.com/someURL
```

Why are no slashes being added in any of these cases?

Comment: you should be using prepared statements fyi

Comment: writing what was supposed to be a quick script with no framework. think the moral of the story is that there's never really a quick script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are no slashes being added in any of these cases?

You don't have any characters that need escaping in that string.

---

That said, `addslashes` is not suitable and `mysql_real_escape_string` (like all of `mysql_`) is [obsolete](/q/12859942/19068), you should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and use [prepared statements / bound arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead of manual string escaping.

Comment: So only backslashes need to be escaped?

Comment: No, quotes need to be escaped as well: they are escaped with the backslash character, which is why the backslash character also needs escaping

Comment: @coderama — No. Apostrophes need it too, and possibly other characters that my knowledge of raw SQL isn't sufficient to know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

**Because** `addslashes()` returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).

and **your string doesnot contain any of the above mentioned characters.**

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.php.net/addslashes:

> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).